# Reused term + Sharepoint + Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, term-store

How can I access reuse terms in powershell. I have total 6 terms out of that 2 are reused, through powershell script I am able to get 4 terms only, The 2 reused terms are not coming, is there any way to get that aswell?

```
$TermStore = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession -ArgumentList $SPSite
$SiteNavigation = $TermStore.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"].Groups |
    Where-Object {$_.TermSets.Name -eq "Site Navigation"} |
    Select-Object -Last 1
#Here I am getting $SiteNavigation properly
$TermId = $SiteNavigation.TermSets["Site Navigation"].Terms["XYZ"].Terms["ABC"].Id
#$SiteNavigation.TermSets["Site Navigation"].Terms Count is returning only 4 even I have 6 values
#$TermId is coming as empty
```

Comment: Can you provide any code or at least the portion that is not working correctly?

Comment: $TermStore = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession -ArgumentList $SPSite
 
$SiteNavigation = $TermStore.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"].Groups | Where-Object {$_.TermSets.Name -eq "Site Navigation"} | Select-Object -Last 1
//Here I am getting $SiteNavigation properly

$TermId = $SiteNavigation.TermSets["Site Navigation"].Terms["XYZ"].Terms["ABC"].Id

//$SiteNavigation.TermSets["Site Navigation"].Terms Count is returning only 4 even I have 6 values
//$TermId is  coming as empty

Answer (score 0):

```
$spInstalled = Get-PSSnapin | Select-String Sharepoint
if (!$spInstalled)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell
}
$termSetName     = "Product Hierarchy"
$productCatalogSiteCollectionURL = <siteurl>
$SpSite          = Get-SPSite $productCatalogSiteCollectionURL
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $SpSite
$termStore       = $taxonomySession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore
foreach($termStoreGroupList in  $termStore.Groups)
{
    if($termStoreGroupList.Name -eq <termstoreGroupName>)
    {
        foreach($termSetList in $termStoreGroupList.TermSets)
        {
            if($termSetList.Name -eq $termSetName)
            {
                foreach($terms in $termSetList.Terms)
                {
                    foreach($subTerms in $terms.Terms)
                    {
                        if($subTerms.IsReused -eq $true)
                        {
                           Write-Host("done " + $subTerms.Name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```